# Using weka in matlab : Undefined weka.core.converters.MatlabLoader

Tags: matlab, weka

I met a problem when i was trying to use weka in matlab.

Can anyone help me?

```
WEKA_HOME = 'C:\Program Files\Weka-3-8';
javaaddpath([WEKA_HOME '\weka.jar']);
loader = weka.core.converters.MatlabLoader();
```

Then i got error message :

```
Undefined variable "weka" or class "weka.core.converters.MatlabLoader".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to import the modules you use like shown in the following example:

```
javaaddpath('C:\Program 

Files\Weka-3-9\weka.jar');

import weka.core.Attribute.*;
import weka.core.FastVector.*;
import weka.core.Instances.*;
import weka.core.DenseInstance.*;
import weka.classifiers.Classifier.*;
import weka.classifiers.bayes.BayesNet.*;
import weka.classifiers.Evaluation.*;
import weka.filters.Filter.*;
import weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove.*;
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you, I've solved it . I found that it's because I didn't install my Java correctly and my version is too high, I use matlab 2013 and I should install jre1.7 instead of using newer version 8 to open my .jar file . After I intall jre1.7 , add javaclasspath and import weka.cores.meta.MatlabLoader.*; It works!